# Where to put a loading icon in this ajax form please anyone tell me?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My code is like this i took it from a tutorial website dont remember where please tell me where to put a loading icon in this huge junk of code i dont understand.
Please show me an example via jsfiddle or anywhere else.

```
  <script language = "javascript" type = "text/javascript">
     <!--
        //Browser Support Code
        function ajaxFunction(){
           var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

           try {
              // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
              ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
           }catch (e) {
              // Internet Explorer Browsers
              try {
                 ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
              }catch (e) {
                 try{
                    ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                 }catch (e){
                    // Something went wrong
                    alert("Your browser broke!");
                    return false;
                 }
              }
           }

           // Create a function that will receive data 
           // sent from the server and will update
           // div section in the same page.

           ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
              if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
                 var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
                 ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
              }
           }

           // Now get the value from user and pass it to
           // server script.

           var age = document.getElementById('age').value;
           var wpm = document.getElementById('wpm').value;
           var sex = document.getElementById('sex').value;
           var queryString = "?age=" + age ;

           queryString +=  "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex;
           ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);
           ajaxRequest.send(null); 
        }
     //-->
  </script>

  <form name = 'myForm'>
     Max Age: <input type = 'text' id = 'age' /> <br />
     Max WPM: <input type = 'text' id = 'wpm' />
     <br />

     Sex: <select id = 'sex'>
        <option value = "m">m</option>
        <option value = "f">f</option>
     </select>

     <input type = 'button' onclick = 'ajaxFunction()' value = 'Query MySQL'/>

  </form>

  <div id = 'ajaxDiv'>Your result will display here</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) out for more info on ready states.

I'd put a loading just before `ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php" + queryString, true);` and remove it on `if (xmlhttp.readyState==4`.

**1.**

So add HTML where you'd like the loading icon to appear:
`<span id="loading"></span>`

**2.**

Then just before `ajaxRequest.open...` insert loading image:

`document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '<img src="loading.gif" />';`

**3.**

And inside `if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4` put:

`document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML = '';`